# How can I customize parameter descriptions in my Google Script function?

Tags: google-apps-script, methods

How do I add description to parameters in google script?

Let's say I have a custom function with "min" and "max" parameters

```
function randomInRange(min, max) {
  var result = min+(Math.random()*(max-min));
  result = Math.round(result);
  Logger.log(result);
  return result;
 }
```

And when I try to use this function google gives me
[these hints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUcgh.png).
Can i change these "any" to something different. "Number", for example?

Comment: Just search for "JSDoc"

Comment: There's an example of the documentation for a custom function _in_ the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions#set_up_the_script). I used this to create a hint like this `randomInRange(min: number, max: number): number`